# Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query for a very short Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am new to this, I have made a very simple schema for a recipe application and created a Stored procedure where it would add new recipes.

When I call the Stored Procedure I keep getting Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query, I feel the the request I am asking should not take any more than 1200 seconds. Which is what I has set my DBMS connection read timeout.

Any advise, have I got something wrong in the procedure script?

I appreciate you reviewing this!
Thank you
Costa!

Below is the schema:

USE myrecipeapp;

```
CREATE TABLE Tags (
  tag_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  tag_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Tags (tag_id, tag_name)
VALUES
  (1, 'Classics'),
  (2, 'Emerging Favourites'),
  (3, 'Cheap & Cheerful'),
  (4, 'Expensive'),
  (5, 'Parties & Snacks');

CREATE TABLE Recipes (
  recipe_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  recipe_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  tag_id INT,
  tag_name VARCHAR(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES Tags(tag_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredients (
  ingredient_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ingredient_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE recipe_ingredients (
  recipe_id INT,
  ingredient_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, ingredient_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES Recipes(recipe_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES Ingredients(ingredient_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

& below is the Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRecipeWithIngredients(
  IN recipeName VARCHAR(255),
  IN tagName VARCHAR(50),
  IN ingredientList TEXT
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE tagID INT;
  DECLARE recipeID INT;

  -- Check if the tag exists
  SELECT tag_id INTO tagID FROM Tags WHERE tag_name = tagName;

  IF tagID IS NULL THEN
    -- Invalid tag name, notify the user
    SELECT 'Invalid tag name' AS message;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      -- Start a transaction to ensure consistency
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' -- Duplicate entry error
      BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        SELECT 'Recipe already exists' AS message;
      END;

      START TRANSACTION;

      -- Insert the recipe into the Recipes table
      INSERT INTO Recipes (recipe_name, tag_id, tag_name) VALUES (recipeName, tagID, tagName);
      SET recipeID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- Fetch the generated recipe_id

      -- Split the ingredient list into individual ingredients
      SET @ingredientList = CONCAT(ingredientList, ',');
      SET @delimiter = ',';
      SET @startIndex = 1;

      WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(@ingredientList) > 0 DO
        SET @delimiterPos = LOCATE(@delimiter, @ingredientList, @startIndex);
        IF @delimiterPos = 0 THEN
          SET @delimiterPos = CHAR_LENGTH(@ingredientList) + 1;
        END IF;

        -- Extract the ingredient from the ingredient list
        SET @ingredient = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@ingredientList, @startIndex, @delimiterPos - @startIndex));

        IF LENGTH(@ingredient) > 0 THEN
          -- Insert the ingredient into the Ingredients table and associate it with the recipe
          INSERT INTO Ingredients (ingredient_name) VALUES (@ingredient);
          SET @ingredientID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
          INSERT INTO recipe_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id) VALUES (recipeID, @ingredientID);
        END IF;

        -- Move to the next ingredient in the list
        SET @startIndex = @delimiterPos + 1;
      END WHILE;

      COMMIT;

      SELECT 'Recipe added successfully' AS message;
    END;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: You don't seem to be changing `ingredientList`, so `WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(@ingredientList) > 0` is likely to run for a long time.

Comment: Many Thanks @500 - Internal Server Error, I've re-worked on this and it finally worked! Thank you very much for your help!